# functional concurrency

Tags: concurrency, functional-programming

when there is some list of advantages of functional languages, there is usually mentioned that it makes concurrency easier because there is not any variables which are subject of change. But, as my assembler-school-lessons-memory knows, there are registers in cpu and memory, that are both mutable. So when the high-level functional code is compiled into some low-lever code, it becomes imperative and mutable. So I'm not understanding what is
the advantage of using functional languages in concurrency. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It's SHARED mutability you need to worry about. Programming languages essentially give you immutibility by making copies (as well as other clever tricks), so it doesn't need to go as far as registers etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's programmers, not computers, that have a hard time with concurrency.  So saying that immutability makes it easier means on humans, not on computers.

(I include compiler writing as a human activity)